# How to group by values withing different keys?

Tags: groovy, group-by

I have a list and i want to group by within those values.

```
 data=[[name:'Test',job:'Dev',exp:2],
       [name:'Test1',job:'Dev',exp:3]]

 data.groupBy{ it.job }
```

Result:

```
[Dev:[[name:Test, job:Dev, exp:2], [name:Test1, job:Dev, exp:3]]]
```

Expected Result:

```
[Dev:[exp:[2,3]]]
```

Comment: Please add the code with what you have tried and what problems you faced, so we can improve from there.

Comment: @cfrick - This is what i tried def item=data.groupBy{it.job} and the result what i am getting is [null:[[Test:[job:Dev, exp:2]], [Test1:[job:Dev, exp:3]]]]

Comment: Not sure what you're doing here. The first line isn't valid groovy

Comment: @tim_yates i am still learning how to do group by on a value with different keys.So can you explain me with an example.

Comment: But what is data supposed to be? A map? Or a list of maps?

Comment: @tim_yates - i edited the code.

Comment: So you could do `​data*.value​.groupBy { it.job​ }` but that won't give you what you say you expect, as what you say you expect isn't valid groovy either

Comment: To make things clear: you can't have a map with same key twice

Comment: @cfrick,@tim_yates:I edited my complete code can you tell me now is it possible to groupby to get my expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `groupBy` alone is not enough to solve that.  You need further shaping of the data.  You are only interested into all the `*.exp` entries of the result.  E.g.

```
def data=[[name:'Test',job:'Dev',exp:2],
    [name:'Test1',job:'Dev',exp:3]]

println(data.groupBy{it.job}.collectEntries{[it.key, it.value*.exp]})
// => [Dev:[2, 3]]
```

Comment: @tim_yates@cfrick- Thank you.